# No se crea la carpeta CSS automáticamente dándole click al botón "Watch Sass" con VSCode

Tags: css, nodejs, vscode, sass

Tengo un problema a la hora de utilizar el "Watch Sass" desde VSCode.
En primer lugar, instalé Node.js (desde la web) y luego instalé la extensión "Live Sass compiler" en VSCode.
Una vez hecho eso, desde la terminal de VSCode escribo el comando "node -v" para saber qué versión de Node tengo y se instaló correctamente. Luego hice lo mismo pero con Sass con el comando "sass --version" (se instaló ok). Hecho eso, escribo el comando "npm init -y" y se me crea el package.json.
Luego escribo el siguiente comando: "npm install bootstrap@next". Hecho esto, crée la carpeta manualmente llamada Sass y dentro de ella el archivo "custom.scss". Dentro de ese archivo custom.scss escribí lo siguiente: "@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";" y le di a guardar.
Y aquí el problema: Cuando le doy click al botón "Watch Sass" queda en "watching" y no pasa nada. En teoría, (según el tutorial que estoy viendo), me debería crear una carpeta CSS con los archivos custom.css y css.map pero no funciona.
La única solución que encontré es hacerlo manualmente desde la terminal, con el siguiente comando: "sass --watch sass/custom.scss css/custom.css"
Cómo puedo hacer para que me funcione el Watch Sass sin necesidad de escribir el comando manualmente para vincular Sass y Css?
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez el problema esté en la configuración del propio Live Sass Compiler.

Crear una carpeta .vscode en tu proyecto (si no la tienes ya) y dentro un archivo settings.json.

La configuración para este plugin puede ser similar a esta:

```html
{
  /* LIVE SASS */
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "compressed",
      "extensionName": ".min.css",
      "savePath": "/css"
    }
  ],
  "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ],
  "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": true,
  "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [
    ".vscode/**",
    "css/**"
  ],
  "liveSassCompile.settings.showOutputWindow": false,
}
```

En resumidas cuentas:

- Le dices que tipo de compresión quieres y dónde quieres que guarde
  los archivos generados.
- También le indicas los parámetros para el prefijo para los diferentes
  exploradores.
- Le indicas, además, si quieres que genere los archivos de mapeo.
  Con esta configuración no deberías tener problemas para que te funcione correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia el mismo problema y asi lo resolvi cambie null por la carpeta donde va estar el CSS o el nombre del archivo para tu CSS. Saludos

```
    {
        // "format": "expanded",
        // "extensionName": ".css",
        // "savePath": null
        

     ------modificacion------

        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/css/"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un Macbook Air y no podía realizar la creación de la carpeta... Hice [lo que indicó Jose Sanzana en su respuesta](/a/471590), pero no funcionaba para mi notebook, pero probé esto: basado en su información, reemplazar así el savePath:  ***"savePath": "/css",*** ... y FUNCIONÓ.  Dejo código.

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [


    {
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/css",
        "savePathSegmentKeys": null,
        "savePathReplaceSegmentsWith": null
    }
],
"vscode-edge-devtools.mirrorEdits": true
```

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges), podrás votar a favor las preguntas/respuestas que te han sido útiles.